# In telerik i am facing/getting Excelworkbook error which states it doe not contain calculate method

Tags: testing, telerik, telerik-test-studio

In telerik i am facing/getting Excelworkbook error which states it doe not contain calculate method

[ Compiler ]
16:27:49 'ERROR' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\Customer FTP Submission.tstest.cs(354,36) : error CS1061: 'ExcelWorkbook' does not contain a definition for 'Calculate' and no accessible extension method 'Calculate' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelWorkbook' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
16:27:49 'ERROR' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\VXC Data Source\TX DMV Data Source.tstest.cs(303,36) : error CS1061: 'ExcelWorkbook' does not contain a definition for 'Calculate' and no accessible extension method 'Calculate' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelWorkbook' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
16:27:49 'ERROR' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\VXC Data Source\FL DMV Data Source.tstest.cs(381,36) : error CS1061: 'ExcelWorkbook' does not contain a definition for 'Calculate' and no accessible extension method 'Calculate' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelWorkbook' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
16:27:49 'WARNING' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\VXC Data Source\Smart Auction Data Source.tstest.cs(317,22) : warning CS0219: The variable 'assert' is assigned but its value is never used
16:27:49 'ERROR' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\VXC Data Source\Smart Auction Data Source.tstest.cs(349,36) : error CS1061: 'ExcelWorkbook' does not contain a definition for 'Calculate' and no accessible extension method 'Calculate' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelWorkbook' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
16:27:49 'ERROR' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\VXC Data Source\eBay Data Source.tstest.cs(275,21) : error CS1061: 'ExcelWorksheet' does not contain a definition for 'Calculate' and no accessible extension method 'Calculate' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelWorksheet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
16:27:49 'WARNING' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\Helper.cs(209,39) : warning CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used
16:27:49 'ERROR' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\VXC Data Source\RMT Auction Data Source.tstest.cs(283,36) : error CS1061: 'ExcelWorkbook' does not contain a definition for 'Calculate' and no accessible extension method 'Calculate' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelWorkbook' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
16:27:49 'WARNING' > C:\Users\Arunreddy\Downloads\telerikacaremote\telerikacaremote\TelerikFTPTests\Helper.cs(794,30) : warning CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used
16:27:49 'INFO' > Build Failed

Answer for above one or how to remove the error